# C2664 Cannot Convert Parameter

Tags: c++, curl, c2664

I am implementing this code but i am receiving an error.

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/ftpupload.html

The error is in this bit of code.

```
static size_t read_callback(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream)
{
  curl_off_t nread;
  /* in real-world cases, this would probably get this data differently
     as this fread() stuff is exactly what the library already would do
     by default internally */ 
  size_t retcode = fread(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);

  nread = (curl_off_t)retcode;

  fprintf(stderr, "*** We read %" CURL_FORMAT_CURL_OFF_T
          " bytes from file\n", nread);
  return retcode;
}
```

Errors are...

```
IntelliSense: argument of type "void *" is incompatible with parameter of type "FILE *"
```

and

```
Error C2664: 'fread' : cannot convert parameter 4 from 'void *' to 'FILE *'
```

Any tips would be useful. I don't understand why we'd pass a void *stream to the function. What does that even mean? A pointer to a void?

It is called here.

```
/* we want to use our own read function */ 
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, read_callback);
```

CURL API

> CURLOPT_READFUNCTION
>
> Pass a pointer to a function that matches the following prototype:
>   size_t function( void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void
>   *userdata); This function gets called by libcurl as soon as it needs to read data in order to send it to the peer. The data area pointed at
>   by the pointer ptr may be filled with at most size multiplied with
>   nmemb number of bytes. Your function must return the actual number of
>   bytes that you stored in that memory area. Returning 0 will signal
>   end-of-file to the library and cause it to stop the current transfer.
>
> If you stop the current transfer by returning 0 "pre-maturely" (i.e
>   before the server expected it, like when you've said you will upload N
>   bytes and you upload less than N bytes), you may experience that the
>   server "hangs" waiting for the rest of the data that won't come.
>
> The read callback may return CURL_READFUNC_ABORT to stop the current
>   operation immediately, resulting in a CURLE_ABORTED_BY_CALLBACK error
>   code from the transfer (Added in 7.12.1)
>
> From 7.18.0, the function can return CURL_READFUNC_PAUSE which then
>   will cause reading from this connection to become paused. See
>   curl_easy_pause(3) for further details.
>
> Bugs: when doing TFTP uploads, you must return the exact amount of
>   data that the callback wants, or it will be considered the final
>   packet by the server end and the transfer will end there.
>
> If you set this callback pointer to NULL, or don't set it at all, the
>   default internal read function will be used. It is doing an fread() on
>   the FILE * userdata set with CURLOPT_READDATA.

I'm a bit out of my depth.

Comment: `fread` takes a `FILE*` as its **fourth** argument, a `void*` does not match. Assuming the argument to `stream` was a `FILE*` before passing it to the parameter, you need to cast it: `fread(..., (FILE*)stream)`

Comment: @0x499602D2 actually, [`fread()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) takes the file as the *last* parameter; not the first. The cast resolution is obviously still correct; just move it =P.

Comment: @WhozCraig Oops! Thanks for pointing that out. Let me fix that. :)

Answer (score 0):

`fread` takes a `FILE*` as its fourth argument, a `void*` does not match. Assuming the argument to stream was a `FILE*` before passing it to the parameter, you need to cast it:

```
 fread(..., (FILE*)stream);
```

BTW a `reinterpret_cast` is more semantically appropriate for this task:

```
fread(..., reinterpret_cast<FILE*>(stream));
```

A `void*` is a generic pointer type that is convertible to any other pointer type.

Answer (score 0):

If your program were written in C then the code would be valid because in C type `void *` can be implicitly converted to pointer of any type. However C++ does not allow to convert implicitly `void *` to pointer of any other type. So you need explicitly specify the type to what you want to convert an object of type `void *`

You can use either C style casting or C++ style casting. For example

```
size_t retcode = fread(ptr, size, nmemb, ( FILE * )stream);
```

or

```
size_t retcode = fread(ptr, size, nmemb, reinterpret_cast< FILE *>( stream ));
```